# how to get attribute information through another attribute in a class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class like this:

```
class School:
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name, number, hour, income):
        self.__class__.instances.append(weakref.proxy(self))
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.hour = hour
        self.income = income
```

And an instance like this:

`n1 = School('Namjoo', 114, 50, 30)`

how can I extract the name attribute by having `114`, `50` or `30`?

I can't use a dictionary as not all the data stays unique

Comment: Use a dictionary for each attribute you want to look up by. Most won't be unique so you'll need to keep a list of objects for each value.

Comment: Do you mean finding out the name of the class instance where e.g. `number == 114`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the name of any class instances that have a particular value set for another attribute, you can walk the `instances` list and check the listed object attributes. For example:

```
print([x.name for x in School.instances if x.number == 114 or x.hour == 50 or x.income == 30])
# ['Namjoo']
```